# In objective-c how to get characters after n-th?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a number which will be represented as string. It is longer than 4 chars. I need to create new string from 5th till the end for that number.

For example if I have 56789623, I need to have 9623 as a result (5678 | 9623).

How to do that?

P.S. I suppose that this is very simple question, but I don't know how properly ask Google about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSString *str = @"56789623";
NSString *first, *second;
if ([str length] > 4) {
    first = [str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 4)];
    second = [str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(4, [str length] - 4)];
} else {
    first = str;
    second = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this Simple functions

```
- (NSString *)substringFromIndex:(NSUInteger)from;
- (NSString *)substringToIndex:(NSUInteger)to;
- (NSString *)substringWithRange:(NSRange)range;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use: 
`- (NSString *)substringFromIndex:(NSUInteger)anIndex`

```
NSString *number = @"56789623";
NSString *result = [number substringFromIndex:4];
NSLog(@"%@", result);
```

`result` contains the string: `@"9623"`

Answer (score 1):

The keywords you were looking for are: `substring` and `range`. There are several ways to use them. Example code split string into 2 equal (if number of characters is even almost equal) substrings:

```
NSString *str = @"56789623";
NSInteger middleIndex = (NSInteger)(str.length/2);

NSString *strFirstPart = [str substringToIndex:middleIndex];
NSString *strSecondPart = [str substringFromIndex:middleIndex];
NSString *strFirstPart2 = [str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, middleIndex)];
NSString *strSecondPart2 = [str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(middleIndex, [str length]-middleIndex)];
```